# menu.asp javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is there a way to access element Menuitem inside asp:menu with javascript
My goal is to changed the imageUrl path when user mouse over the menu.

```
  <div align = "center">
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
        <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl = "Images/education_remo_un.gif"></asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
        </asp:Menu>

    </div>
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Take a look at the rendered html using tools like firebug. Asp.net's default implementation uses a lot of nested tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One nice approach to apply hover functionality is to assign a cssclass to menuitems and set the image in that cssclass.

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
    <DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="menu-item-selected" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="menu-item-selected" />
    <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="menu-item-hover" />
    <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="menu-item-hover" />
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 1" Selectable="true" Selected="true"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 2" Selectable="true"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 3" Selectable="true"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: How about if i want to change background image to each item